# How to store Json response in class variable?

Tags: apex, rest-api

I am new to REST API and I have written the REST class and got the JSON Response as below.
I want to store Max and Remaining values in two different variables in my apex class? could someone help me with the approach, please? Thanks in advance!

```
         DEBUG|>>>>>>{Max=5000, Remaining=5000}
```

Apex Lines:

```
         String sfdcURL = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm(); 
         String restAPIURL = sfdcURL + '/services/data/v45.0/limits/';  
         HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();  
         httpRequest.setMethod('GET');   
         httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + 
         UserInfo.getSessionId());        
         httpRequest.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
         UserInfo.getSessionID()); 
         httpRequest.setEndpoint(restAPIURL);  
       try {  
            Http http = new Http();   
            HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);  
        if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200 ) {  
           Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody());
           string aID = String.valueof(results.get('SingleEmail')); 
        } 
        else {  
           throw new CalloutException( httpResponse.getBody() );  
        }   
        } catch( System.Exception e) {  
         System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);  
     throw e;  
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right you can either use the same method  You can generate a class based on the JSON structure.

```
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(httpResponse.getBody());
string aID = String.valueof(results.get('SingleEmail'));
Map<String, Object> results = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(aID);
String maxValue = String.valueof(results.get('Max'));
String remaining = String.valueof(results.get('Remaining'));
```

**Alternative approach:**

Assuming that you JSON is

```
{ 
   SingleEmail: {
     "Max":5000, 
     "Remaining":5000
   }
}
```

You can paste it at

```
public class LimitsJson{
    public cls_SingleEmail SingleEmail;
    class cls_SingleEmail {
        public Integer Max; //5000
        public Integer Remaining;   //5000
    }
    public static LimitsJson parse(String json){
        return (LimitsJson) System.JSON.deserialize(json, LimitsJson.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can use:

```
LimitsJson result = LimitsJson.parse(httpResponse.getBody());
String maxValue = result.Max;
String remaining = result.Remaining;
```

Comment: Hi @manjit5190, I am getting the json as posted in the question. that doesn't have the double quotes.

Comment: Actually that is the debug value not the actual JSON. If you want to see actual JSON, you can print the http response.

Comment: I just updated the code in the question, could you please take a look once, if I did any mistake?

Comment: This code is the get the governor limits, you may directly execute this code once in the dev console without any changes.